# Obtain Azure Access Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

i am getting this nasty error, i have no idea what i am doing wrong here. My code even looks quite similar to the one found on this blog, but in my case this is not working.

[GetAzureAccessToken](https://zimmergren.net/developing-with-azure-resource-manager-part-3-build-an-application-using-c-which-is-using-the-azure-resource-manager-apis/)

Error message

> "'authority' Uri should have at least one segment in the path (i.e. https:////...)\r\nParameter name: authority"

```
public static string GetAzureAccessToken(string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        string tenandId = "{tenandId}";
        string loginUri = $"https://login.windows.net/";

        var authCtx =
            new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, loginUri, tenandId));
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientSecret);

        var result = authCtx.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/",
            clientCredential: credential);

        if(result == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to aquire token");

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You define the authority wrong, it should be:

```
var authCtx = new AuthenticationContext(loginUri + tenantId);
```

Also, I guess it does not really matter, but I use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id` as authority usually.

Comment: i have problem with the (loginUri + tenantId), lets say my tenandid is "abcd2344/jskkeh234" then the url becomes https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcd2344/jskkeh234" but due to / the requested uri will be "https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcd2344/" and it will be wrong tenandid

Comment: There are no slashes in a tenant id. It is a UUID/GUID. Alternatively you can use one of the verified domain names in the Azure AD tenant, e.g. tenantname.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: strange...who i am getting a / let me double check on this

Comment: You can find the tenant id by going to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Properties

Comment: Looks like i was using serviceprincle key as tenandId :P Thansk